# Python Pandas : group by in groups by and average, count, median

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
d = {'User' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
     'time':[1,2,3,4,4,4],
     'state':['CA', 'CA', 'ID', 'OR','OR','OR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Now suppose I want to create new dataframe that takes the average and median of time, grabs the users state, and generate a new column as well that counts the number of times that user appears in the `User` column, i.e.

```
d = {'User' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'avg_time':[1.5,3,4],
     'median_time':[1.5,3,4],
     'state':['CA','ID','OR'],
     'user_count':[2,1,3]}

df_res = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I know that I can do a group by mean statement like this

```
df.groupby(['User'], as_index=False).mean().groupby('User')['time'].mean()
```

This gives me a pandas series, and I assume I can make this into a dataframe if I wanted but how would I do the latter above for all the other columns I am interested in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [pd.NamedAgg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter#named-aggregation):

```
df.groupby('User').agg(avg_time=('time','mean'),
                       mean_time=('time','median'),
                       state=('state','first'),
                       user_count=('time','count')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  User  avg_time  mean_time state  user_count
0    A       1.5        1.5    CA           2
1    B       3.0        3.0    ID           1
2    C       4.0        4.0    OR           3
```

Comment: This is more robust due to namedAgg

Comment: Can we apply `agg` to get an average of a column that is of type `string`?

Comment: Uh... nope.  you want mode? `state=('state',pd.Series.mode)`

Comment: nvm, what if we did that as an function on each User. So instead of `df.groupby().agg()` we would do `df.groupby().apply(some_function)`, then we could parallelize the function to gather all the metrics we want?

Comment: Please refer to this new post if you want more clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492527/using-groupby-apply-instead-of-groupby-agg

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you.  This was very helpful.  Side note for future readers - you can also group by more than one col by replacing ('User') above with (['User', 'Other_Col_Name']).

Answer (score 2):

You can even pass multiple aggregate functions for the columns in the form of dictionary, something like this:

```py
out = df.groupby('User').agg({'time': [np.mean, np.median], 'state':['first']})

     time        state
     mean median first
User                  
A     1.5    1.5    CA
B     3.0    3.0    ID
C     4.0    4.0    OR
```

It gives multi-level columns, you can either drop the level or just join them:

```py
>>> out.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in out.columns]

      time_mean  time_median state_first
User                                    
A           1.5          1.5          CA
B           3.0          3.0          ID
C           4.0          4.0          OR
```

Comment: That works, thank you. If I wanted to get different column names though, how would I do that? Say I wanted to have the mean time to say `avg_time` and vice versa for the rest?