# Using `.groupby().apply()` instead of `.groupby().agg()`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
d = {'User':['A', 'A', 'B'],
     'time':[1,2,3],
     'state':['CA', 'CA', 'OR'],
     'type':['cd', 'dvd', 'cd']}
df = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
```

I want to create a function that where I will pass in a single users dataframe so for example

```
user_df = df[df['User'] == 'A']
```

Then the function will return a single row data frame that will look like this

```
d = {'User':['A'],
    'avg_time':[1.5],
    'state':['CA'],
    'cd':[1],
    'dvd':[1]}
res_df = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
```

Then that function will be used to apply this across the entire dataframe of users, so I will have

```
def some_function():
```

Then I will write `df.groupby('User').apply(some_function)`. Then I will have this as the resulting new dataframe

```
d = {'User':['A','B'],
    'avg_time':[1.5, 3],
    'state':['CA', 'OR'],
    'cd':[1, 1],
    'dvd':[1, 0]}
final_df = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
```

I know I can grab values for the `df` like this

```
avg_time = user_df['time'].mean()
state = user_df['state'].iloc[0]
type_counts = user_df['type'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

But I am not sure how to tranform this into a results row dataframe. Any help is appreciated. The reasoning on why I want to do it in this way instead of `.agg()` is because I am going to parallelize this function to make it run faster since I will have a very large dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
def aggUser(df):
    a = pd.DataFrame({'avg_time':df['time'].mean(), 
                      'state': [df['state'].iloc[0]]})
    b = df['type'].value_counts().to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
    return pd.concat([a,b], axis=1).set_axis(df['User'].iloc[[0]])

pd.concat([aggUser(df.query('User == "A"')),
           aggUser(df.query('User == "B"'))])
```

Output:

```
      avg_time state  cd  dvd
User                         
A          1.5    CA   1  1.0
B          3.0    OR   1  NaN
```

---

```
df.groupby('User', group_keys=False).apply(aggUser)
```

Output:

```
      avg_time state  cd  dvd
User                         
A          1.5    CA   1  1.0
B          3.0    OR   1  NaN
```

Comment: @Justanewb I suspect you should consider using [Dask](https://dask.org/).